# Why PDO connection sowing "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error"?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**I am using pdo connection.** I am trying to run a delete query but it is showing this message in the browser

```
*SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error*
```

Here is my query:

```
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];  $result = query($conn, "DELETE  FROM user WHERE user_id = '$user_id'");
```

I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Answer (score 0):

Per MySQL 5.5.35 source code, `sql/sql_prepare.cc`:

```
bool
Reprepare_observer::report_error(THD *thd)
{
  /*
    This 'error' is purely internal to the server:
    - No exception handler is invoked,
    - No condition is added in the condition area (warn_list).
    The diagnostics area is set to an error status to enforce
    that this thread execution stops and returns to the caller,
    backtracking all the way to Prepared_statement::execute_loop().
  */
  thd->stmt_da->set_error_status(thd, ER_NEED_REPREPARE,
                                 ER(ER_NEED_REPREPARE), "HY000");
  m_invalidated= TRUE;

  return TRUE;
}
```

It appears that your error (SQL state HY000) will happen when there is a wrong sequence of prepare/execute statements. Double-check our logic to make sure you are properly using prepared statements, e.g properly fetching all of the results after the call to `query()` before calling it again.

UPDATE:

Does the problem go away (or do you at least get a meaningful error message) if you do

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

prior to the query?

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a query() function does not exists in PHP .. It should be mysql_query or mysqli_query

Using Mysql query is bad because it is depreciated in Updated version of php

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE  FROM user WHERE user_id = '$user_id'");

//So using mysqli :) 

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE  FROM user WHERE user_id = '$user_id'");
```

Comment: What if `query` is just user written function? PHP would throw error if such function did not exist.